# Animation conflict between Qt and VTK integration

Tags: qt, render, vtk

I'm facing an issue in my Qt application that involves animation using VTK (Visualization Toolkit). My animation works seamlessly when using native VTK rendering. However, when Qt starts managing the rendering via vtkGenericOpenGLRenderWindow, the animation ceases to work. In the Qt version, the cube view doesn't smoothly rotate but abruptly ends up at the final point.

Are there specific settings or methods that should be used to ensure the proper integration of VTK animations within a Qt environment?

```
for (int frame = 0; frame < self->animatorTotalFrames_; ++frame)
{
    viewCubeWidget->InterpolateCamera(frame);
    viewCubeWidget->parentRenderer_->ResetCamera();
    viewCubeWidget->Render();
}
```

When examining the differences in the `Render()` calls, I observed the following:

In the native VTK scenario, we directly execute `vtkOpenGLRenderWindow::Render()`. However, in the Qt application, `vtkGenericOpenGLRenderWindow::Render()` is invoked, which internally calls `vtkOpenGLRenderWindow::Render()`.

```
void vtkGenericOpenGLRenderWindow::Render()
{
  if (this->ReadyForRendering)
  {
    vtkOpenGLCheckErrorMacro("error before running VTK rendering code");
    if (!this->Initialized)
    {
      this->OpenGLInit();
    }
    this->MakeCurrent();
    if (!this->IsCurrent())
    {
      vtkLogF(TRACE, "rendering skipped since `MakeCurrent` was not successful.");
    }
    else
    {
      // Query current GL state and store them
      auto state = this->GetState();
      state->Reset();
      state->Push();

      this->Superclass::Render(); // CALLED vtkOpenGLRenderWindow::Render()

      // Restore state to previous known value
      state->Pop();
    }
    vtkOpenGLCheckErrorMacro("error after running VTK rendering code");
  }
}
```

```
void vtkOpenGLRenderWindow::Render()
{
  if (this->Initialized)
  {
    vtkOpenGLRenderUtilities::MarkDebugEvent("Starting vtkOpenGLRenderWindow::Render");
  }
  this->Superclass::Render();

  if (this->FirstRenderTime < 0)
  {
    this->FirstRenderTime = vtkTimerLog::GetUniversalTime();
  }
  this->GetShaderCache()->SetElapsedTime(vtkTimerLog::GetUniversalTime() - this->FirstRenderTime);

  if (this->NoiseTextureObject && this->GetTextureUnitForTexture(this->NoiseTextureObject) >= 0)
  {
    this->NoiseTextureObject->Deactivate();
  }
  if (this->Initialized)
  {
    vtkOpenGLRenderUtilities::MarkDebugEvent("Completed vtkOpenGLRenderWIndow::Render");
  }
}
```

**I tried searching for a solution, but the one I found didn't work for my case.**

```
for (int frame = 0; frame < self->animatorTotalFrames_; ++frame)
{
    self->InterpolateCamera(frame);
    self->parentRenderer_->ResetCamera();
    self->Render();
    QCoreApplication::processEvents();
}
```