# fluid camera movement in VTK

Tags: qt, camera, interpolation, vtk

I want to implement an operation of double clicking the model and smoothly moving the camera.like his discription .I don't know what happens when I interpolate the camera.
I'm facing an issue in my Qt application that involves animation using VTK (Visualization Toolkit). My animation works seamlessly when using native VTK rendering. However, when Qt starts managing the rendering via QOpenGLNativeWidget, the animation ceases to work. In the Qt version, the cube view doesn't smoothly rotate but abruptly ends up at the final point.
I meet the same problem as his [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77324620/animation-conflict-between-qt-and-vtk-integration).can anyone tell me how to implement an operation of double clicking the model and smoothly moving the camera with VTK and QT?

i used vtkCameraInterpolator and vtkAniamtionScene. when i don't use qt ,it can show properly.